# Getting JSON Array from top/new category of Reddit in Java not working as expected

Tags: java, android, json

I am passing the url https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/top/.json into my method for getting the JSON array of a subreddit. However, it only returns the JSON array for the hot category rather than the top or new categories. I have checked the URL and code thoroughly and have tried other different formats of the URL to only get the same results. For some reason all JSON gets all return only the hot page or default subreddit URL. But when I visit the URL in my browser that I've linked, it displays the correct JSON array for the top category. (Android Studio)

Here's the beginning of my JSON task that returns the array:

```
private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = null;

                try {
                    stream = connection.getInputStream();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Subreddit Closed", urlString);
                    connection.disconnect();
                    return null;                            //if can't retrieve JSON file
                }

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                return buffer.toString();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Update: This was an issue with Reddit's API, it is now working as expected. Take caution of URL formats as */hot/.json is equivalent to */.json

Comment: please give me json which return through this code  by .........putting log inside your code..................

Comment: can you post how you are calling asynctask and how you are passing URL